# Possible to use Gii funcationlity from the command line?

Tags: php, command-line, yii

I'm new to Yii (coming from the world of Django, Rails, etc) and wondering if it is possible to to use the Gii scaffolding functionality for controllers, models, views, etc. from the command line.

I'm interested in creating a site from scratch and not building off the site that is packaged with the framework.

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "not building off the site that is packaged with the framework" ?

Comment: "yiic webapp <name>" creates a dummy site. I'd rather build from the bottom up than having to start with that dummy site, while retaining the ability to use Yii's model/view/controller scaffolding functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use YIIC's shell to create controllers and models from command line

```
%YiiRoot/framework/yiic shell

>> controller message helloWorld
generate MessageController.php
mkdir /Webroot/demo/protected/views/message
generate helloworld.php
generate index.php
Controller 'message' has been created in the following file:
/Webroot/demo/protected/controllers/MessageController.php
You may access it in the browser using the following URL:
http://hostname/path/to/index.php?r=message
>>
```

~Agile Web Application Development with Yii 1.1 and PHP5 {book}

hope this helps